# Unable to boot into Windows install disk on a Kubuntu machine with full disk encryption

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, encryption, kubuntu

The machine I'm working on is an Asus N81V laptop, Core 2 Duo, 4GB of RAM, SSD. It currently has Kubuntu 13.10 with full disk encryption.

I am trying to repurpose this machine with Windows 7. I have the install disk and am trying to boot from the disk, but it will not boot from the disk. It will read the disk for a few seconds, but then it continues to the initial password prompt screen for decrypting the drive.

Things I've done so far:

- Confirmed in BIOS proper boot order (CD/DVD drive first).
- I can press escape and manually choose a boot device. Doing this and selecting the CD/DVD drive still does not result in booting from the CD.
- Put the windows disk on a USB stick and attempted to boot from that, with no luck.

I have installed many OS's on this machine over the years, and have never had issues booting from install disks. I'm assuming the issue has something to do with the fact that the machine is set up with full disk encryption.

Is there a way to deactivate the full disk encryption? I've read up a little and I'm pretty sure I'd have to decrypt the entire drive first. But I don't know the steps required to accomplish that task. Also, since I am repurposing the machine, I don't need to spend the time decrypting the drive.

Ultimately, I would just like to boot from the Windows disk and reformat the drive. If I have to spend the time and decrypt the drive first, then that would be fine.

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to repurpose the machine with Windows 7. I created a startup disk USB in Kubuntu using the [Startup Disk Creator](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/usb-creator-gtk/) and a Kubuntu ISO. I then reinstalled Kubuntu using that startup disk. I then created a Windows 7 startup disk USB using the [Windows 7 USB/DVD Download tool](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool) and a Windows 7 ISO (on a separate windows machine). I was then able to boot from the USB and install Windows.